# Image tensors don't match filenames and labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

```
training_set_name, training_set_class, training_set_image = sess.run([fR.training_set_name, fR.training_set_class, fR.training_set_image])
```

Relevant code of the fileReader class.

```
def return_training_set():
    image_tra_name_batch, image_tra_class_batch = labelFileBatchProcessor(50, 1, "training")
files_training = filenameLister2(image_tra_name_batch)

images = build_images(files_training)
return image_tra_name_batch, image_tra_class_batch, images

training_set_name, training_set_class, training_set_image = return_training_set()
```

The labelFileBatchProcessor reads the csv, shuffles, and returns a batch containing names and labels.  `Filenamelister()` converts these names to paths, it returns a queue. This queue is passed to an `imageloader()` function, which returns the image tensors.

The problem is that the loaded image tensors and the `image_tra_name_batch` do not match. I think the problem is that another bath is loaded when `build_images(files_training)` is excuted. Is there a fix for this?

I want to avoid storing everything in one file and prefer to read the image names from the csv, shuffle it and then the images.

---

Edit1: Some relevant functions

labelFileBatchProcessor function:

```
 def labelFileBatchProcessor(batch_size, num_epochs=None, what_set="training"):
        if what_set == "training":
            inputCsv = ["./data/BDRW_train/BDRW_train_1/labels.csv"]
        elif what_set == "validation":
            inputCsv = ["./data/BDRW_train/BDRW_train_2/labels.csv"]
        labelFile_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(inputCsv, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
        image_name, image_class = labelFileInit(labelFile_queue)
        min_after_dequeue = 50
        capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
        image_name_batch, image_class_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
            [image_name, image_class], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
            min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
        return image_name_batch, image_class_batch
```

filenameLister2 function:

```
def filenameLister2(imageNameBatch):
    FILES_TRAINING = TRAINING_DIR + imageNameBatch + ".jpg"
    FILES_TRAINING = tf.train.string_input_producer(FILES_TRAINING, name="CSVFilenames")
    return FILES_TRAINING
```

build_images function:

```
def build_images(files_training):
image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
_, image_file = image_reader.read(files_training)
image_orig = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file)
image = tf.image.resize_images(image_orig, [48, 48])
image.set_shape((48, 48, 3))
num_preprocess_threads = 1
min_queue_examples = 256
images = tf.train.batch([image], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, num_threads=NUM_PREPROCESS_THREADS, capacity=BATCH_SIZE)
return images
```

---

EDIT2

I updated the `labelFileBatchProcessor()` function and removed `tf.train_batch()` from `build_images()`. This may be caused by a different issue.  I put the tensors in the same batch the images still don't match.

```
def labelFileBatchProcessor(batch_size, num_epochs=None, what_set="training"):
if what_set == "training":
    inputCsv = ["./data/BDRW_train/BDRW_train_1/labels.csv"]
elif what_set == "validation":
    inputCsv = ["./data/BDRW_train/BDRW_train_2/labels.csv"]
labelFile_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(inputCsv, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)

image_name, image_class = labelFileInit(labelFile_queue)
min_after_dequeue = 50
capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size

filenames = [TRAINING_DIR + image_name + ".jpg"]

files_training = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, name="CSVFilenames",  shuffle=False)
images = build_images(files_training)

image_name_batch, image_class_batch, images, filenames2 = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [image_name, image_class, images, filenames], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
    min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)

return image_name_batch, image_class_batch, images, filenames2
```

Comment: The most likely cause of such an error is that the `sess.run()` call is evaluating tensors from different "stages" in the input pipeline (e.g. upstream and downstream of a call to `tf.train.batch()`). It's hard to say for certain without seeing the rest of the code, however.

Comment: Hi, I've just added the relevant functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the problem arises because there are two independent batching stages in your input pipeline:

- `image_tra_name_batch` and `image_tra_class_batch` are batched by the [`tf.train.shuffle_batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/shuffle_batch) in `labelFileBatchProcessor()`.
- `images` are batched by the [`tf.train.batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch) in `build_images()`.

As a result, the association between each filename and class, and each image is lost. The general solution to a problem like this is to ensure that all attributes of a training example (in this case, `image_name`, `image_class`, and `image`) are passed to the same `tf.train.batch()` (or `tf.train.shuffle_batch()`) call. This will ensure that they are preprocessed as an indivisible tuple of tensors, and the association will be maintained.

Comment: I've updated the code (see edit 2), but I still have matching problems.

Comment: It's still hard to tell from the code fragments, but another potential problem is that there are multiple `tf.train.string_input_producer()` calls, which end up creating multiple queues behind the scenes, and hence opportunities for mismatched elements. I'd suggest trying to rewrite it as straight-line line code, using a single `tf.train.string_input_producer()`, `tf.read_file()` instead of `tf.WholeFileReader`, and a single call to `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` at the end of the pipeline.

Comment: That worked. I didn't need to change a lot.

By replacing `tf.WholeFileReader` by `tf.read_file()`, which uses tensors instead of a queue, I could remove the `tf.train.string_input_producer()` for loading the images.

The images match the filenames and the labels now.


Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it!